# ftp.ControlChannelIOException: Connection reset

Tags: talend

I have an issue when executing a simple job in talend.
The FTPPut component is in error:
"com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.ControlChannelIOException: Connection reset
at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.readLine(FTPControlSocket.java:1090)
at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.readReply(FTPControlSocket.java:1150)
at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.sendCommand(FTPControlSocket.java:1049)
at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.createDataSocketPASV(FTPControlSocket.java:876)
at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.createDataSocket(FTPControlSocket.java:632)
at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.createDataSocket(FTPClient.java:2756)
at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.dir(FTPClient.java:3918)
at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.dir(FTPClient.java:4023)
at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.dirDetails(FTPClient.java:3837)
at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.existsFile(FTPClient.java:2161)
at mac_talend.extraction_mail_qualnet_0_1.extraction_mail_qualnet.tFTPPut_1Process(extraction_mail_qualnet.java:1617)
at mac_talend.extraction_mail_qualnet_0_1.extraction_mail_qualnet.tFTPConnection_1Process(extraction_mail_qualnet.java:1449)
at mac_talend.extraction_mail_qualnet_0_1.extraction_mail_qualnet.tPOP_1Process(extraction_mail_qualnet.java:1227)
at mac_talend.extraction_mail_qualnet_0_1.extraction_mail_qualnet.runJobInTOS(extraction_mail_qualnet.java:2257)
at mac_talend.extraction_mail_qualnet_0_1.extraction_mail_qualnet.main(extraction_mail_qualnet.java:2106)"

Connection is fine on FileZilla. I have other jobs to different FTP that works perfectly but not this one.

Talend is 7.3.1.
I checked window firewall to allow java.exe in and out but no difference.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: could you show us your job design and if the connection to ftp is initialzed , it's preferable to show us your configuration .

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa : here's the picture: https://imgur.com/a/6fkpfKL
Nothing special I guess?

Comment: I really need an answer: why it is not working with that FTP while it is ok with all the others?!
Thanks a lot!